# PHP method for stripping duplicate chars from a multibyte string?

Tags: php, multibyte-functions

Arrrgh.  Does anyone know how to create a function that's the multibyte character equivalent of the PHP count_chars($string, 3) command?

Such that it will return a list of ONLY ONE INSTANCE of each unique character.  If that was English and we had

"aaabggxxyxzxxgggghq xcccxxxzxxyx"

It would return "abgh qxyz"  (Note the space IS counted).

(The order isn't important in this case, can be anything).

If Japanese kanji (not sure browsers will all support this):

漢漢漢字漢字私私字私字漢字私漢字漢字私

And it will return just the 3 kanji used:

漢字私

It needs to work on any UTF-8 encoded string.

Comment: In the accepted answer below, the first script is designed to remove CONSECUTIVE duplicates only.  The other scripts in the answer are overly verbose.  See the advice on the dupe target.  Also note in another answer that `str_split()` is not multibute/unicode safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey Dave, you're never going to see *this* one coming.

```
php > $kanji = '漢漢漢字漢字私私字私字漢字私漢字漢字私';
php > $not_kanji = 'aaabcccbbc';
php > $pattern = '/(.)\1+/u';
php > echo preg_replace($pattern, '$1', $kanji);
漢字漢字私字私字漢字私漢字漢字私
php > echo preg_replace($pattern, '$1', $not_kanji);
abcbc
```

What, you thought I was going to use `mb_substr` again?

In regex-speak, it's looking for any one character, then one or more instances of that same character.  The matched region is then replaced with the one character that matched.

The [`u` modifier](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) turns on UTF-8 mode in PCRE, in which it deals with *UTF-8 sequences* instead of 8-bit characters.  As long as the string being processed is UTF-8 already *and* PCRE was compiled with Unicode support, this should work fine for you.

---

*Hey, guess what!*

```
$not_kanji = 'aaabbbbcdddbbbbccgggcdddeeedddaaaffff';
$l = mb_strlen($not_kanji);
$unique = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $l; $i++) {
    $char = mb_substr($not_kanji, $i, 1);
    if(!array_key_exists($char, $unique))
        $unique[$char] = 0;
    $unique[$char]++;
}
echo join('', array_keys($unique));
```

This uses the same general trick as the shuffle code.  We grab the length of the string, then use `mb_substr` to extract it one character at a time.  We then use that character as a key in an array.  We're taking advantage of PHP's positional arrays: keys are sorted in the order that they are defined.  Once we've gone through the string and identified all of the characters, we grab the keys and join'em back together in the same order that they appeared in the string.  You also get a per-character character count from this technique.

This would have been much easier if there was such a thing as `mb_str_split` to go along with [`str_split`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php).

(No Kanji example here, I'm experiencing a copy/paste bug.)

---

Here, try this on for size:

```
function mb_count_chars_kinda($input) {
    $l = mb_strlen($input);
    $unique = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < $l; $i++) {
        $char = mb_substr($input, $i, 1);
        if(!array_key_exists($char, $unique))
            $unique[$char] = 0;
        $unique[$char]++;
    }
    return $unique;
}

function mb_string_chars_diff($one, $two) {
    $left = array_keys(mb_count_chars_kinda($one));
    $right = array_keys(mb_count_chars_kinda($two));
    return array_diff($left, $right);
}

print_r(mb_string_chars_diff('aabbccddeeffgg', 'abcde'));
/* => 
Array
(
    [5] => f
    [6] => g
)
*/
```

You'll want to call this *twice*, the second time with the left string on the right, and the right string on the left.  The output will be different -- `array_diff` just gives you the stuff in the left side that's missing from the right, so you have to do it twice to get the whole story.

Comment: Charles, thank you for the code!  It's almost what I need, but the returned values still have duplicate characters.  "abcbc" has 2 "b"s and 2 "c"s.  I just need it to return "abc" (one instance ONLY of each unique character.)  It seems like somehow it needs to check the current character against a prexisting list, add the character if it's missing, and NOT add it if it is already there.  I know mentally how to do it, just that I'm not a programmer and don't know how to get it to do that in code.  >_<

Comment: Ah, I misread your question -- I thought you were looking for duplicate sequential character removal, when you just wanted all of the unique characters in the string.  I'll update my answer in a bit.

Comment: I can't thank you enough, Charles.  This is exactly what I needed.  And it works just fine with kanji too!

Comment: Okay, now I'm noticing something very strange. This is with a HUGE string that includes (I hope!) every Japanese, Korean, and Roman-Latin-European character and punctuation.The string (according to mb_strlen) has 9080 chars to start. 30 are not unique. So I end up with a 9050 length string. I use the output of the first function above to get just a unshuffled list, length 9050. Then I shuffle that output, and get 9050 again. HOWEVER, when I then copy those two (unique, unshuffled) and (unique, shuffled) strings into my program they're consistently a few characters off! Any idea why?

Comment: Are those characters *always* in UTF-8, and are you including the encoding in the various calls to the `mb_` functions?  I excluded them here because I wasn't completely sure what charset you were using.

Comment: Doing more research, I noticed that while the original string contained a "h" (regular roman, normal "h") the new processed string doesn't.Somehow, this character (and others) are being lost. I'm stumped, but my one thought is maybe this won't work on a string that's mixed with regular alphanumerals as well as things like kanji or hangul? The string is so long it's hard to pick through and see what characters are missing.Can I possibly ask a 3rd function: compare 2 strings and show only the characters that are NOT in both strings? Either way, thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: As it happens, you can take the results of the `array_keys` calls here for the two strings, then use [`array_diff`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) to get the difference.

Comment: Trying to put this together on my own: array_keys($not_kanji) and array_keys($unique)?  then something like:  $diff = array_diff(array_keys($not_kanji), array_keys($unique));

Comment: 1: Take one string and run it through the process.  Stick `array_keys($unique)` in a variable.  2: Take the other string and run it through the process.  Stick `array_keys($unique)` in another variable.  3: `$diff = array_diff($var1, $var2);`, tada!

Comment: Okay, almost getting it.  I've put your code above into a function and am currently returning the last "join" as the output.  If I assign array_keys($unique) to a variable will that be available outside the function?

Comment: I tried doing this (tried posting my code but it's too long to fit) and am getting a return value of "Array" -- am betting I'm not doing it right.  Super sorry to be consuming so much of your time.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: The string "Array" means you managed to turn an array into a string using a string operator.  PHP is nice enough not to complain about this.  I'll c&p together something for you in a few moments.  :)

Comment: @Dave, I've added two functions and an example to my question.  Hopefully that'll be the last thing you need, this comment area is getting a bit long!

Comment: Works, Charles!!  I was doing "echo" but clearly "print_r" is vital to the equation!  Thanks so much.  I WON'T pester any more!!  You've been a huge help!

Comment: @Dave, glad to hear you got it working.  Yeah, `echo` just handles strings, if you need to inspect an array, `print_r`, `var_dump` and `var_export` are all good tools.

Comment: Okay,I'm going to post a new question, because sure enough, these two arrays are _different_ and they should be the same.I am running the first function (string A), to remove duplicate chars,which goes from 9098 chars to 9050 (string B).  Then I shuffle the 9050 and get at third string (string C).However (if this third function is outputting correctly, and I think so because I can SEE that one string is longer) for some reason the two resulting strings (B and C) DO have different characters! Why would that be?(You've done enough,so I'm posting a new question...thanks so much for the help! :-)

Comment: @Charles, will these functions work on strings that are in "&#x0E2007; &#x0B004; etc." format?  I'm realizing it would (maybe?) be better to do these functions in Unicode UTF-8.

Comment: @Dave, no, it'll process those literally.  You might want to run the strings through [`html_entity_decode`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) first, to convert those entities into real characters.  Take note of the last argument, which is the character set that will be used during the decode.

Comment: I'm thinking I might do it (assuming this is doable!) by reading each value up through the semi-colon into an array, then shuffling the array elements or comparing the array elements to see if they're identical.  If &#x0E388 and another &#x0E388 exist, it shouldn't be too hard to tell those are the same.  Thanks (again) for the help!!

Comment: @Dave, while comparing the two *encoded* strings against each other for similarity will work, when you compare it to the actual represented character, it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to check the [iconv_strlen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv-strlen.php) PHP standard library function. Can't say about orient encodings, but it works fine for european and east europe  languages. In any case it gives some freedom!

Comment: This doesn't seem to have the option to return the unique chars though, just the _number_.  I need a way to take a string and reduce it to only its unique chars.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: no you are not missing, I mentioned the iconv as the only known to me the php library which is able to deal with the multibyte encodings. Another option would be to use the database backend and make something like DISTINCT selection and counting etc.

Comment: Okay, no, what I need is the _3_  (above count_chars($string, 3)) which shows the characters, not a number.  But thanks anyway.  Still hoping to figure this out somehow...

Answer (score 0):

```
$name = "My string";
$name_array = str_split($name);
$name_array_uniqued = array_unique($name_array);
print_r($name_array_uniqued);
```

Much easier.  User str_split to turn the phrase into an array with each character as an element.  Then use array_unique to remove duplicates.  Pretty simple.  Nothing complicated.  I like it that way.